# Smooth case of Jordan Brouwer Separation Theorem; proving there is more than 1 connected component

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Im having trouble proving something. I am using smooth degree theory to prove the Jordan Brouwer Separation Theorem for a smooth compact connected oriented $n$ dimensional surface $M \subset \mathbb{R}^{n + 1}$. Let $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^{n + 1} \setminus M$. For each $p \in \Omega$ define a map $F_p \colon M \to S^n$ by
$$F_p(x) = \frac{x - p}{||x - p||}.$$
I have shown that the degree of $F_p$ is constant on each connected component of $\Omega$. In order to prove that there is more than one connected component, it suffices to show that there are two points $p_0, p_1 \in \Omega$ such that the degrees of $F_{p_0}$ and $F_{p_1}$ differ. If I can find a point $p \in \Omega$ such that $F_p$ has a regular value with nonempty inverse image, then the rest of the proof is easy, but I am not able to prove that such a $p \in \Omega$ exists. Any help on proving (or disproving) this is appreciated.

I think this is equivalent to showing that there exists a ray $r$ that is never tangent to $M$ and intersects $M$ at least once.

Comment: Why don't you just use Sard's theorem? In order to apply it you have to show that $F_p(M)$ is nonempty interior. The latter will follow from finding a pair of points $p\in \Omega, x\in M$ such that the segment $px$ is transversal to $M$. In fact, any $p\in \Omega$ would work for this purpose.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I ended up using Sard's theorem. I chose $p \in \Omega$, $x \in M$ such that $x - p \perp T_xM$ and then showed that $F_p'(x)$ was an isomorphism. By the inverse function theorem, this then implies that $F_p(M)$ contains an open subset $V$ of $S^n$, and since $V$ cannot have zero volume, Sard's theorem implies $V$ contains a regular value of $F_p$. Is this the proof you had in mind?

Comment: That's right................

Answer (score 1):

Since $M$ is flat, locally (in the neighborhood of some point $x_0$) it looks like a hyperplane. From the local picture it is clear all non-tangent at $x_0$ directions are regular values.

Comment: But for some direction $v$ to be a regular value of $F_p$, it must be that $x - p \notin T_xM$ for all $x \in F^{-1}(\{v\})$ since $\ker F_p'(x) = T_xM \cap \text{span}(x - p)$. So it is not enough for the direction to only be not tangent at $x_0$ right?